# How to get keys and key types of nested json using jq

Tags: json, types, key, jq

I have a file data.json like below -

```
     { 
       "parameter": {
        "colA": "No",
        "COLB": "No"
      },
      "workRequired": 0,
      "work": 0,
      "updateType": "AUTO"
}
```

I know how to get the key and key type of json -

```
jq -c 'to_entries[] | [.key, (.value|type)]' data.json
```

but the above command returns me -

```
["parmeter","object"]
["workRequired","string"]
["work","null"]
["updateType","number"]
```

but I want the command to return like below, so that I get key type of nested json -

```
["parmeter"."colA","string"]
["parmeter"."colB","string"]
["workRequired","string"]
["work","null"]
["updateType","number"]
```

Is there any way to do using jq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets very close to the requested output.

```
jq -c 'to_entries[] 
       | if .value|type == "object"
         then .key as $k 
            | .value
            | to_entries[]
            | ["\($k).\(.key)", (.value|type)]
         else [.key, (.value|type)]
         end'
```

Output:

```
["parameter.colA","string"]
["parameter.COLB","string"]
["workRequired","number"]
["work","number"]
["updateType","string"]
```

The main difference is in the first two lines. I don't think that `["parameter"."colA","string']` is valid json.

Some of the types are different as well.

**Explanation**

One way of learning how this stuff works is to go step by step. So start with `jq -c 'to_entries[]'` to see what comes out and then add each step in turn. The [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) is also quite good.

Here, we start with an object. The first command is `to_entries[]`. To quote the manual, when "to_entries is passed an object, then for each k: v entry in the input, the output array includes {"key": k, "value": v}." Adding `[]` at the end means the output will just be the objects in the array that `to_entries` produces. So this is the output after the first step:

```
{"key":"parameter","value":{"colA":"No","COLB":"No"}}
{"key":"workRequired","value":0}
{"key":"work","value":0}
{"key":"updateType","value":"AUTO"}
```

Now we have four objects. One contains another object. The original question concerns the object that contains an object. The problem was to combine the key for the containing object with the key for the contained object in the final output.

The conditional `if .value|type == "object"` identifies the object that contains an object.

When this condition is met, `.key as $k` saves the value of the containing object's "key" key as a variable named $k.

Then we repeat `to_entries[]` with the contained object. The contained object is the value of the key "value" in the containing object. The code `.value | to_entries[]` filters the contained object through `to_entries[]`. That gives us these two objects.

```
{"key":"colA","value":"No"}
{"key":"COLB","value":"No"}
```

To create the desired output, we need to construct an array that combines the key of the containing object, which was saved as $k, with the elements of those two objects. Here is how we do that. (See "String interpolation" in the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) for an explanation of how the part in quotes works.)

```
["\($k).\(.key)", (.value|type)]
```

For each object, the key we saved as the variable $k is combined with the value of the "key" key in the object. Then we output the type of the value of the "value" key in the object.

This yields the first two lines of the final output:

```
["parameter.colA","string"]
["parameter.COLB","string"]
```

Now we move to the other branch of our conditional. This deals with the three objects from the first step that do not contain objects. Here we just repeat the original code from the question since that was satisfactory.

```
else [.key, (.value|type)]
```

That yields this:

```
["workRequired","number"]
["work","number"]
["updateType","string"]
```

The command `end` ends the conditional.

One more thing. The flag `-c` at the very beginning tells jq we want compact output. Without it, the output would be logically the same, but spread over multiple lines.